# Using Angular2 String Interpolation to Pull Data from an Array of Objects in a Mongo DB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, typescript

I'm developing an app where I'm pulling data from a mongo database. I'm using string interpolation to pull in the data and print it to the view. It's working as expected for basic object data. So for instance, I'm able to take this from the db:

```
"name": {
  "prefix": "",
  "suffix": "",
  "first": "",
  "middle": "",
  "last": ""
}
```

... and print it to the component view with string interpolation - like this:

```
{‌{record.name.first}} {‌{record.name.last}}
```

The component is subscribing to an observable I've set up in a service. In the component it looks like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.streamVisitingService.getByCat()
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => this.records = resRecordsData, 
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
}
```

Abd here's the relevant code from my service:

```
constructor(private _http: Http) {}

getByCat() {
    return this._http.get(this._url)
        .map((response:Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this._errorsHandler);
}
_errorsHandler(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error || "Server Error");
}
```

My problem/challenge comes in trying to print to the screen data that's within an array of objects. How do I target a specific field/value that is within an object within an array? It may be obvious, but for some reason the answer is escaping me.

Comment: if you can tell us how `resRecordsData` looks like and what exactly you want to display from it, probably will be helpful in solving

Comment: You have everything relevant here. There's nothing I'm not showing that's relevant. Unless you can specifically tell me what you'd like to see? Basically, my question is, how do I pull data that is a field within an object that is within an array of objects? I'm doing it successfully for a basic object - as I describe above. But I'm not sure how to do it when it's an object within an array of objects in the db.

Comment: ok, let me try:  you want to find an object which is inside an array, and then display a value from this object ? then you will need to `Array.filter` in `es5` or `Array.find` in `es6` or you can also use a simple `for loop` and you can also turn that function of yours into a `Pipe`

Comment: So you're suggesting I do the logic in my Angular2 component, using something like array.filter. And then I store the result of that in a variable, and then use that variable to be evaluated in the view. Yes?

Comment: yes. and if you don't want to store it, you can also make an `Angular2 Pipe` out of it with some `arguments` so that it will be generic and reusable

Comment: Can you give me a basic idea of what such a filter function would look like for a nested object value within an array?